# Click event in parent and children

Tags: jquery

I have a parent element DIV that has children div elements. I have separate click implementations for parent and its children.

```
<div id="mainContainer">

    <div id="childContainer">    
    </div>

     <div id="childContainer2"> 
    </div>

</div>

$('#mainContainer').click(function () {

        console.log('main container');

    }).children().click(function () {
        console.log('childen');
        return false;
    });

    $('#childContainer2').click(function () {

        console.log('child container 2');

    });
```

This is working fine. but if I click a child then the event runs twice which is how it is supposed to work. My question is - Is there a way that I can explicitly write event to parent that would not affect children so that children need not execute click function twice?

Comment: Sorry can you explain again what you need

Comment: what is your expected result http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hF6L9/1/

Comment: You are binding two event handlers to the second child. Do you only want to run one of them and if yes, which one? You might be looking for `event.stopImmediatePropagation`: http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/.

Comment: @FelixKling also order is important

Comment: @ArunPJohny, If parent has click event then when i click on its children, it executes first. So I had to explicitly write for its children to return false. But this solution causes a click function to run twice one in parent.children().click() and one in children.click(). How to avoid this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

yes you can just, change the order of binding the events and to stop propagation use [stopImmediatePropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/)

consider this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AHyN5/)

```
$('#childContainer2').click(function (e) {       
       alert('child container 2'); 
        e.stopImmediatePropagation()
     return false;
    }); 
$('#mainContainer').click(function () {
alert('main container');

    }).children().click(function (e) {
       alert('childen');
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use use [event.stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/):

```
children().click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log('childen');
    return false;
});
```

to prevent event buble up

Answer (score 3):

Both `return false;` & `event.stopPropagation` stops event propagation to the parent.

Here is the [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vt2dt/).

Comment: return false with also do the preventDefault() hence not recommended when you only want to stop propagation.