# differentiate the clicks between parent and child using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 elements nested called blanket and blanket-content and I want to recognize the clicks done to the parent alone.

```
<div id="blanket">
    <div id="blanket-content"></div>
</div>
```

The issue that I'm having is that when I'm clicking the child it is triggering the parent on click. I've tried different methods yet I was unsuccessful.
I have tried these to play around with my code;

```
$('#blanket').on('click', function(ev) {
    alert(ev.currentTarget.id); //
});
```

^ This triggers the click on div as normal and state the parent id even when the child is clicked.

```
$('#blanket-content').on('click', function(ev) {
        alert(ev.currentTarget.id);
});
```

^ This doesn't trigger anything

What I want to achieve is when I click on blanket-content nothing will happen, but when I click on blanket I want to do something.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery: click event in parent and children](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20561035/jquery-click-event-in-parent-and-children)

Comment: Can you post code in jsfiddle. because its working in jsfidle as https://jsfiddle.net/92jwad1w/

Comment: @UmeshSehta use aruh link: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3gLe7gfz/2/

Comment: @Joseph118 , the code working fine in link: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3gLe7gfz/2/

Comment: @Joseph118 , are u getting issue with link ?

Comment: @UmeshSehta I had a css issue which disabled the onclick effect with jquery

Comment: @Joseph118 , But m not getting the css ? Css section is empty

Comment: @Joseph118 , can you provide me the link, where css is added.

Comment: @UmeshSehta sorry I must have gave you the wrong link, this is the one http://jsfiddle.net/3gLe7gfz/4/

Comment: @Joseph118 , good you got your solution. I think also my answer was correct. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One easy solution is to stop the event propagation in a click handler of the `blanket-content`, so that it will trigger the parent element's click handler.

You can use [Event.stopPropagation()](https://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) to do that

```js
$('#blanket').on('click', function(ev) {
  alert(ev.currentTarget.id); //
});


$('#blanket-content').on('click', function(ev) {
  ev.stopPropagation()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="blanket">blanket
  <div id="blanket-content">blanket-content</div>
</div>
```

---

Another solution([why](https://css-tricks.com/dangers-stopping-event-propagation/)) is to check whether the click happened in the `blanket-content` element inside the `blanket` click handler

```js
$('#blanket').on('click', function(ev) {
  if (!$(ev.target).closest('#blanket-content').length) {
    alert(ev.currentTarget.id); //
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="blanket">blanket
  <div id="blanket-content">blanket-content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I had no luck with stopPropagation() so far and no the click is not triggering in #blanket-content

Comment: whether `#blanket-content` is created dynamically?

Comment: @Joseph118 , Which jquery version are you using  ?

Comment: @Joseph118 can you try to recreate the issue - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3gLe7gfz/1/

Comment: This is the code I'm looking for however I don't know why the child div is not being triggered.. @UmeshSehta I'm using the latest version of jQuery, downloaded it last week edit- v214

Comment: @ArunPJohny I have updated the link you gave me, take a look. after being modified with the css it doesn't work

Comment: @Joseph118 it is because you have set `pointer-events: none` for `blanket-content` which prevents the click event from the child being triggered

Comment: @ArunPJohny i found my issue why it wasn't being triggered.. I had 
    pointer-events: none; in my css. I've deleted it before, must have did undo to a certain point that i got it back

Answer (score 3):

No need to do more. Just add ev.stopPropagation(); inside #blanket-content click event.

```
<div id="blanket">PARENT
    <div id="blanket-content">CHILD</div>
</div>


$('#blanket').on('click', function(ev) {
    alert(ev.currentTarget.id); //
});


$('#blanket-content').on('click', function(ev) {
    ev.stopPropagation();
    alert(ev.currentTarget.id);
});
```

Check here: https://jsfiddle.net/92jwad1w/

Answer (score 0):

Try preventing the Default action, stop propogation doesn't always work if it is still being referenced.

```
$('#blanket').on('click', function(event){
    $(event).preventDefault();
});
```

this will stop the default action of a click event and will work well.

for more information, go  [here](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)